# Customisable, reversible XML serialisation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

[Ox](https://github.com/ohler55/ox) and similar libraries provide the serialisation of ruby objects to XML, but are there any libraries which allow you to define the form that serialisation takes?

Essentially, is there a library akin to (haml|slim|mustache) which allows you to define the mapping of a hash (lets say) to an XML document, but which can *also* parse the XML document and generate the original hash?

(assuming all the elements of the hash are mapped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the mapping is not too exotic, you might be able to do it with [representable](https://github.com/apotonick/representable). It also supports JSON, by the way.